# 2 Different Custom Post Types in Submenu

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, admin-menu

i have register 2 custom post types within my plugin one of them is shown in the left admin bar, the second i wouldn't show so i have set the "show_ui" to false.

Is it possible to add the second post type to the menu of the first post type?

**first post type:**

```
$args = array(
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => false,
  'menu_position' => 100,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
  'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/img/small1.png', __FILE__ ),
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'screenshots', 'with_front' => true)
);

register_post_type( 'screenshots', $args );
```

**second post type:**

```
$args = array(
  'show_ui' => false,
  'labels' => $labels,
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => false,
  //'menu_position' => 100,
  'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
  //'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'assets/img/small2.png', __FILE__ ),
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'deal', 'with_front' => true)
);

register_post_type( 'deals', $args );
```

**I try to add the second post type with:**

```
add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=deals', __('Deal', $this->var_sTextdomain), __('Deal', $this->var_sTextdomain), 'manage_options', 'my-deal', array(&$this, 'deal_page') );
```

What can i do to add it to the first post type at the end?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CPT has a parameter called `show_in_menu` to add it to a specific menu.

You must set you CPT to `'public' => true`

Then in your deals `$args`  (it's unclear which one you wanted added ) add something like,

```
'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=screenshots'
```

You can then adjust it accordingly.

Comment: the menu from the first post type will show but the data from the second not, i have try your answer but the second will not add ...

Comment: `show_ui` must also be set to true, please review the docs for `show_in_menu` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type.

Comment: my fail - it works - it wasn't show at the end :(